# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I just started to learn implementing `react` on `rails` following a tutorial. There were similar questions asked earlier and I tried those solutions, but they didn't seem to work.

I installed `react-rails` gem.

And added following lines to `appication.js`

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
```

My rails version is **5.1.4** and jQuery version is **1.12.4**

I am just trying to get a simple **Hello React** as follows.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="react"></div>
```

**main.jsx**

```
let documentReady = () => {
    React.render(
        <h1>Hello React</h1>,
        document.getElementById('react')
    );  
};


$(documentReady);
```

At first I was getting a `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` then I added the following line on the top of **main.jsx**

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then I started getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

So instead of a plain **Hello React** I am getting all of these errors. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your main.jsx, import React first and second the library to render is ReactDOM, not React itself, so you need both React and ReactDOM to be in the scope.

Comment: @Jay I added these lines `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` in **main.jsx**. Now I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`